# how to retrieve data from multiple colums from bulk collect

Tags: plsql

```
DECLARE
   TYPE two_cols IS RECORD
   (
      family_id   family_members.family_id %TYPE,
      city     family_members.city%TYPE
   );

   TYPE family_members_t IS TABLE OF two_cols;

   l_family_members   family_members_t;
BEGIN
   SELECT family_id,city 
   BULK COLLECT INTO l_family_members
   FROM (SELECT x.family_id, x.City, x.Member_count,row_number() 
         OVER (PARTITION BY x.family_id ORDER BY x.Member_count DESC) rn
         FROM (SELECT family_id, City, COUNT(*) Member_count
               FROM FAMILY_MEMBERS
               GROUP BY family_id, City) x) y
   WHERE y.rn = 1;

   for rec in 1..l_family_members.count 
   loop
       dbms_output.put_line('majority mem of family id' 
           || l_family_members.family_id(rec)
           || 'stay in '||l_family_members.city(rec));
   end loop;
END;
```

Error:

> ORA-06550: line 23, column 69: PLS-00302: component 'FAMILY_ID' must
>   be declared ORA-06550: line 23, column 1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

I am confused at the output line.. I am not getting how to retrieve data from bulk collect as there are two columns in it..how to distinguish them and retrieve them?

Comment: I am confused at the output line.. I am not getting how to retrieve data from bulk collect as there are two columns in it..how to distuinguish them and retrieve them?

Comment: Not `l_family_members.family_id(rec)`, use `l_family_members(rec).family_id` instead.

Comment: Why is this tagged for MySQL?  It looks like you're using Oracle not MySQL

Comment: You probably don't need to use `BULK COLLECT` anyway.  If you use a cursor for-loop Oracle will automatically bulk collect records.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to select 2 columns into 1 record which doesn't work.
depending on your database version, you may be able to select records which then get bulk collected into a table as follows

```
DECLARE
   TYPE two_cols IS RECORD
   (
      family_id   family_members.family_id %TYPE,
      city     family_members.city%TYPE
   );

   TYPE family_members_t IS TABLE OF two_cols;

   l_family_members   family_members_t;
BEGIN
   SELECT two_cols(family_id,city )
   BULK COLLECT INTO l_family_members
   FROM (SELECT x.family_id, x.City, x.Member_count,row_number() 
         OVER (PARTITION BY x.family_id ORDER BY x.Member_count DESC) rn
         FROM (SELECT family_id, City, COUNT(*) Member_count
               FROM FAMILY_MEMBERS
               GROUP BY family_id, City) x) y
   WHERE y.rn = 1;

   for rec in 1..l_family_members.count 
   loop
       dbms_output.put_line('majority mem of family id' 
           || l_family_members(rec).family_id
           || 'stay in '||l_family_members(rec).city);
   end loop;
END;
```

NB: I also fixed the reference in the output loop to put the `(rec)` after the table and before column

Comment: whats with the down vote?  is this wrong in someway?